# Problema al usar GoogleAuthenticator de PHPGangsta

Tags: php, pdo

Hola quiero añadir un sistema de 2fa y tengo problemas este es mi script

```
<?php
//2fa.php
require 'PHPGangsta/GoogleAuthenticator.php';
$authenticator = new PHPGangsta_GoogleAuthenticator();
$secret = $authenticator->createSecret();
$website = 'https://azuranetwork.tk'; //Your Website
$title= 'AzuraNetwork';
$qrCodeUrl = $authenticator->getQRCodeGoogleUrl($title, $secret,$website);
echo "Open this link in browser & scan with Google Authenticator App \n";
//echo $qrCodeUrl."\n";
echo "<a href='$qrCodeUrl'> ".$qrCodeUrl." </a>";

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])){


$otp = $_POST['key'] ;//Generated by Authenticator.

$tolerance = 0;
            //Every otp is valid for 30 sec.
            // If somebody provides OTP at 29th sec, by the time it reaches the server OTP is expired.
            //So we can give tolerance =1, it will check current  & previous OTP.
            // tolerance =2, verifies current and last two OTPS

$checkResult = $authenticator->verifyCode($secret, $otp, $tolerance);    

if ($checkResult) 
{
    echo 'OTP is Validated Succesfully';

} else {
    echo 'FAILED';
}

}

?>

<form method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="text" name="key">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

por otro lado tengo un archivo index con el formulario de login que redirige a un archivo auth.php para validar el usuario

esto de aqui es lo que esta en la cabecera de mi index.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
require('admincp/config.php');
require('function.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {

}else {
  header('Location:'.RUTA.'home');
}

$message = '';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {



  $username = specialtext($_POST['username']);
  $password = specialtext($_POST['password']);
  $password = hash('sha512', $password);

  $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=remotemysql.com;dbname=',"","");
  //$conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE usuario = :username AND pasword = :password");
  $statement->bindParam(':username', $username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $statement->bindParam(':password', $password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $statement->execute();
  $result = $statement->fetch();
  if ($result !=false) {
    if (isset($result['auth']) == "yes"){
         $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result['user_id'];
          $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
          $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
          $_SESSION['pass'] = $password;
          $_SESSION['av'] = $result['avatar'];
          $_SESSION['id'] = $result['id'];
          $_SESSION['userID'] = $result['userID'];
          $_SESSION['nombre'] = $result['nombre'];
          $_SESSION['tipo'] = $result['tipo'];
          $data = [
          'online' => 'yes'
          ];
          $sql = "UPDATE user SET online=:online WHERE id=$id";
          $stmt= $conexion->prepare($sql);
          $stmt->execute($data);


          header('Location:'.RUTA.'2fa');
          exit;
    }else{
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result['user_id'];
    $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['pass'] = $password;
    $_SESSION['av'] = $result['avatar'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $result['id'];
    $_SESSION['userID'] = $result['userID'];
    $_SESSION['nombre'] = $result['nombre'];
    $_SESSION['tipo'] = $result['tipo'];
    $data = [
    'online' => 'yes'
    ];
    $sql = "UPDATE user SET online=:online WHERE id=$id";
    $stmt= $conexion->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($data);


    header('Location:'.RUTA.'auth');
    exit;
    }
  }else {
    $message .= '<span class="error">Usuario o contraseña incorrecto</span>';
  }
}elseif(isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['password'])){ //este metodo es para una api de logeo de apps externas
  $usern = $_GET['username'];
  $userp = $_GET['password'];
  $username = specialtext($usern);
  $password = specialtext($userp);
  $password = hash('sha512', $password);

  $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=remotemysql.com;dbname=',"","");
  //$conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE usuario = :username AND pasword = :password");
  $statement->bindParam(':username', $username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $statement->bindParam(':password', $password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $statement->execute();
  $result = $statement->fetch();
  if ($result !=false) {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result['user_id'];
    $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['pass'] = $password;
    $_SESSION['av'] = $result['avatar'];
    $_SESSION['id'] = $result['id'];
    $_SESSION['userID'] = $result['userID'];
    $_SESSION['nombre'] = $result['nombre'];
    $_SESSION['tipo'] = $result['tipo'];
    $data = [
    'online' => 'yes'
    ];
    $sql = "UPDATE user SET online=:online WHERE id=$id";
    $stmt= $conexion->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($data);


    header('Location:'.RUTA.'auth');
  }else {
    $message .= '<span class="error">Usuario o contraseña incorrecto</span>';
  }
}


?>
```

```
//Formulario en el index
   <form class="" action="" method="post">
            <p class="title">Iniciar Secion</p>
            <div class="errors">
              <?php if(!empty($message)): ?>
              <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> <?php echo $message;  ?>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="input-grup">
              <input type="text" class="user form-control" name="username" placeholder="Usuario" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="input-grup">
              <input type="password" class="pass form-control" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" value="">
            </div>
            <div class="input-grup">
              <a class="reg" href="register">Registrar</a>
              <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-main derecha" value="Entrar">
            </div>
          </form>
```

```
//auth.php
<?php session_start();
require('admincp/config.php');
require('function.php');
if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
  header('Location:'.RUTA.'');
  exit;
}else {
  header('Location:'.RUTA.'home');
  exit;
}
$conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=remotemysql.com;dbname=',"","");
$username = login('user',$conexion);

//print_r($username['usuario']); Esta parte solo es una prueba
?>
```

```
//function.php
function login($table,$conexion)
{
  $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table");
  $statement->execute();
  return $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

ahora bien no redirecciona o eso es lo que entiendo que tiene que hacer

alguien tiene idea de que puedo estar haciendo mal? intente moviendo todos los archivos de lugar y poniendo manualmente las claves pero no me funciona, los archivos son de este enlace https://github.com/PHPGangsta/GoogleAuthenticator

Comment: La consulta `SELECT * FROM $table` obtendrá TODOS los registros de la tabla, pero tú haces un `print_r($username['usuario']);` sin ni tan siquiera hacer un `fetch` de los registros devueltos por la consulta. Por otro lado no se sabe cuándo entra en juego el primer PHP que publicas. Si pusieras el nombre de los script PHP podríamos intentar imaginarnos cómo se entrelazan en tu código.

Comment: @OscarGarcia el codigo de login lo saque de una web y funciona por otro lado los nombres de los archivos los puse fíjate en el codigo los puse en el comienzo `print_r($username['usuario']);` lo use para comprobar si el login funcionaba con la db